# How to replace a word with an increasing number

Tags: xml, bash, sed, awk

I've about 1600 items in my XML-feed which contains several lines per item and one of them is  `<g:id>omg</g:id>`. I want to replace omg in an bash-script with an increasing number
i.e `<g:id>1</g:id>`  ..... `<g:id>2</g:id>` etc

I've trying a lot of sed and awk commands but none of them are doing it like I want it to be.
Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: Do you want to replace every occurrence of the string `omg` with an increasing number? Could you post some sample input and output?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you've tried already?

Comment: you could use sed but increasing value is a hard ressource consumption (sed is not made for), especially compare to awk in this kind of action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using gnu `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="omg"; ORS=""} {print $0""++i}' file
```

This will replace every occurrence of string *omg* with number of increasing sequence. i.e 1,2,3,...

Comment: This will only work with `gnu awk` due to  multiple characters in `RS`

Comment: @Jotne I don't have much idea as it worked on both of my machines. I hope it's not difficult to get `gnu awk` installed

Comment: It just a comment. Its important to note other user when using special switches in any program.  Like `gensub` that is only in `gnu awk` and the `RS` variable mention.

Comment: @Jotne Appreciate your comments. It's just that I don't have an experience on older version of `awk`. Added `gnu` term in my ans.

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {RS="omg"; ORS=""} {print $0""++i}' file did the trick, many thanks !